# How to get smallest value (stride) for particular number type in Swift?

Tags: swift

How to get smallest value (stride) for particular number type in Swift? I mean, the shortest non-zero stride.
For example `1` for `Int`, `0.00...001` for `Double` etc...

Comment: Actually the smallest `Int` value (`Int.min`) is `-9223372036854775808`

Comment: I mean, the shortest non-zero stride.

Comment: `(0 as Type).successor` for integer types would work.  There really isn't a stride for floating types as even adding `1000` to a sufficiently large value such as `1e80` wouldn't change the value.

Comment: @user500 for Int 0.successor() gives you 1, as expected. for Double the minimal value you can add or remove to change the value depends on the value self.

Comment: Double has a precision of at least 15 decimal digits, whereas the precision of Float can be as little as 6 decimal digits.

Comment: see http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been partially addressed in separate comments already, but to bring it all together...

#### For integer types:

The smallest possible increment between distinct values is 1. This is part of the definition of an integer, so it's such a foundational aspect of the type that there isn't (and needn't be) a special API for finding it.

(One can argue that `successor` constitutes such an API. But one can also argue that using `successor` where you could just use `1` makes your code much less readable.)

#### For floating-point types:

*There is no one smallest possible increment.* Because floating-point types use an exponent-based representation, the spacing between representable floating-point numbers varies with the exponent, as illustrated in this number line:

[image: density of floating point numbers]
That image comes from [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#690), an essential read for, well, everyone using floating-point numbers. You can read more about the concept in Wikipedia's pages for [Unit in the Last Place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) and [Machine Epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon). [Exploring Binary](http://www.exploringbinary.com/the-spacing-of-binary-floating-point-numbers/) also has a good entry-level read on floating-point spacing.

Back to Swift — The `Float` and `Double` types conform to the [`FloatingPoint` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpoint) (in Swift 3, currently in beta). This defines the features of [IEEE 754 floating point formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), which includes both:

- The Unit in the Last Place, or [`ulp`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpoint/1847492-ulp), which tells you the increment between a number and the next greater representable number (but for some edge cases). This is related to, but not the same as, machine epsilon, since it scales with value. ([`ulpOfOne`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpoint/1846373-ulpofone) is the same as what other libraries call machine epsilon.)
- [`nextUp`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpoint/1848104-nextup) and [`nextDown`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpoint/1845543-nextdown), which tell you the closest greater or lesser representable numbers.

Here's an example (conveniently showing that for 32-bit `Float`, the minimum increment gets bigger than one sooner than you might think):

```
let ichi: Float = 1.0
ichi.ulp    // -> 1.192093e-07
ichi.nextUp // -> 1.00000012

let man: Float = 10_000
man.ulp    // -> 10000
man.nextUp // -> 10000.001

let oku: Float = 100_000_000
oku.ulp    // -> 8
oku.nextUp // -> 100000008.0
```

In Swift 2, there's no `FloatingPoint` protocol, but you can make use of the equivalent POSIX constants/functions imported from C: `FLT_EPSILON` and `DBL_EPSILON` are defined as the difference between 1.0 and the next representable value, and the [`nextafter`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/nextafter.html) functions find the increment at any value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get these numbers by importing `Darwin` and the numbers you're looking for will be

```
DBL_MIN
FLT_MIN
Int.min
```

However these won't be 'nice' numbers like 0.00 ... 01 and `Int` will be signed so using `Uint8.min` will give you 0.